# Custom sort all the rows in dataframe in one order excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file which contain row values in non organized manner.I want to organize every row by aligning same data dedicated to one column.
For example:

[image]

I would like to format the file as:
[image]

The attribute name and its value should be copied as well  across every row and not just the attribute name.

Python Code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import glob

    for f in glob.glob("../Book1.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)

    df1=df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x.values), axis=1)
```

But it is sorting all the values in below format:[image]

I want the sorting of only Attribute column and Value column should be attached to Attribute always. i.e Paper Size have value Legal so while sorting it should attached to Paper_size only and not to other attribute.

Can this be achieved in python ?
Thankyou

Comment: How does python programming relate to this? There's no code in question. Can't you just copy/paste within excel to get your desired result?

Comment: I have updated the question to include code!! Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more "pythonic" and "pandas" way to do it but I couldn't find one, rather manually renaming the column names is the only way I could get that result:

```
# Using your same code
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x.values), axis=1)

cols = df1.columns.tolist()

new_cols = [cols[4], cols[3], cols[1], cols[7], cols[5], cols[2], cols[6], cols[0]]

df2 = df1[new_cols]

df2.columns = ['Attribute_1', 'Value', 'Attribute_2', 'Value', 'Attribute_3', 'Value', 'Attribute_4', 'Value']
```

Now `df2` looks like:

```
    Attribute_1  Value   Attribute_2   Value Attribute_3 Value Attribute_4 Value
NaN  Paper_size  Legal  Color_family  Yellow   Ring_type     D    Tab_type   A-Z
NaN  Paper_size  Legal  Color_family  Yellow   Ring_type     D    Tab_type   A-Z
NaN  Paper_size  Legal  Color_family  Yellow   Ring_type     D    Tab_type   A-Z
NaN  Paper_size  Legal  Color_family  Yellow   Ring_type     D    Tab_type   A-Z
```

which seems to match the output in your second image.

It's not great, but I thought I'd put it here until someone offers a better solution.

Comment: Thankyou!! Yeah even I could find the solution by manually arranging columns and its value. But I was wondering what if the values are not same then again its difficult to arrange manually.